# SQL select statement, I need to connect to 2 separate linkserver db's for data comparison

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, linked-server

I need to connect to 2 separate SQL Server linked server connections to compare data from the same source.  The issue is, when I use the same query in both SQL servers I end up with different results.

**SQL Server 2005 one:**

```
Select * 
From OPENQUERY ( DB1, 'select * from 1_view')
```

Results: example 3000 rows

**SQL Server 2008 two:**

```
Select * 
From OPENQUERY ( DB1, 'select * from 1_view')
```

Results: example 3060 rows

Comment: the problem with this type of question is that we can't know if you simplified too much, or if you are using a query just like the one posted. Because those don't have the database as a prefix of the view (or the schema), so they can be pointing to different views

Comment: The query is exactly as posted, not using real dba name and view of course.  But each query was run on each server with different results.  I can't figure out how to make a 2008 query that look at the linkedserver from the 2005 server.  They are pointing to the same view and getting different results.

Comment: as I said, you are not using the database name and schema: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DB1,'select * from database.dbo.1_view')`

Comment: correction:  SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( db1, 'select * from XXX.XXVIEW')

Comment: jeez, that's why I explicitly asked about it. So, you *are* using database name and  schema?. Then I don't know, maybe the linked servers were created differently

Comment: I'd suggest to use the Profiler to monitor, what's going on. Since you've got two different databases on two different servers, ockham's razor would lead to: **There is not the same count of rows in the two sources**. Try to combine the resultsets and find out, which 60 rows are different. Are they 60 here which are missing there or is it mixed and overlapping? Are the missing rows in the datasource? If yes: Why might they be overlooked?

Comment: Lamak:  I can run my select query in either 2005 or 2008 Server and receive results accessing the same source.  The problem is the results do not match and they have the same linkedserver.  My request is, is there a method to run one query from the 2008 Server, using the 2008 linked server and join the 2005 linkedserver so I can identify the 60 secords?  The linkedservers are created exactly the same.   Thank you Shnugo I appreciate it.    I will just export each results to excel and run a compare, will take me seconds to do that.  Was hoping to do it in sql and learn a little.

Comment: Rebuild all the indexes and update the  statistics for the base table of the view.

Comment: Are two linked servers connect same physical server? Can you execute 'select @@SERVERNAME' against both linked servers to confirm it's pointed to the same server and instance?

Comment: Thanks all, I simply ran each query to a file and compared the data.  Both Servers have the exact same linked server.